# Why is my regex not parsed correctly on sms receiver in android?

Tags: java, android, regex

In my android application I am parsing sms received through broadcast.

I put my regex in string.xml

```
<string name="message_verification_regex">^.*Your Verification Code is \\d{4}.*$</string>
```

And message I am trying to parse is

```
1234567890:
Your Verification Code is 5840.
Team ABC
-
Reply via way2sms.com. Now available on your mobile.
```

What is wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is a multiline string, but the dot does not match newline characters. Use

```
<string name="message_verification_regex">^[\\s\\S]*?Your Verification Code is \\d{4}[\\s\\S]*$</string>
```

The expression `[\s\S]` matches any whitespace character and any non-whitespace character which means really any character.

I must add that I don't know if escaping a backslash with an additional backslash is really necessary where the string with this regular expression is used. Therefore try also:

```
<string name="message_verification_regex">^[\s\S]*?Your Verification Code is \d{4}[\s\S]*$</string>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked like charm. additional backslash is needed because string is parsed from xml thats why.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `(?m)` at the start of your regex. That way, `^` will match the start of any line (instead of the start of your string, i.e. start of the 1st line only):

```
<string name="message_verification_regex">(?m)^.*Your Verification Code is \\d{4}.*$</string>
```